# Loop through XML with same node-values

Tags: c#, xml, loops, recursion, linq-to-xml

I have difficulties looping through an XML file and representing it in for example a TreeView. The structure of my XML looks like this:

```
<Categories>
  <Category Name="Cat Level1">
    <Categories>
      <Category Name="ChildCat Level 2">
        <Categories>
          <Category Name="ChildCat Level3_1" />
          <Category Name="ChildCat Level3_2" />
        </Categories>
      </Category>
    </Categories>
  </Category>
</Categories>
```

I wrote a recursive function to loop through this XML, here it is:

```
private void CreateTreeStructure(XDocument xDoc)
{
    foreach(var element in xDoc.Descendants("Category"))
    {
        var node = new TreeNode(element.Attribute("Name").Value);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
        ReadChildren(element.Descendants("Categories"), node);
    }
}

private void ReadChildren(IEnumerable<XElement> element, TreeNode node)
{
    foreach (var child in element.Descendants("Category"))
    {
        var childNode = new TreeNode(child.Attribute("Name").Value);
        node.Nodes.Add(childNode);
        ReadChildren(child.Descendants("Categories"), childNode);
    }
}
```

The result is expected and non-expected. I want this XML in a TreeView so the result should look  something like:

- Cat Level 1

  - ChildCat Level2

    - ChildCat Level3_1
    - ChildCat Level3_2

But the result looks like this:

- Cat Level 1

  - ChildCat Level2

    - ChildCat Level3_1
    - ChildCat Level3_2
  - ChildCat Level3_1
  - ChildCat Level3_2
  - ChildCat Level3_1
  - ChildCat Level3_2
- ChildCat Level2

  - ChildCat Level3_1
  - ChildCat Level3_2
- ChildCat Level3_1
- ChildCat Level3_2

After some debugging I found that this is because my recursive code is looking for descendants "Category", but the sub-categoriy nodes are also named "Category". So, the first function which should only find the element "Cat Level 1", also loops over the other nodes named Category. Now I'm kind of stuck on this and I cannot change the structure of the XML.

So, does anyone have an idea how I can loop this XML without reading **all** the childnodes everytime? Thanks in advance!

### Update:

Thanks to the answer of *"davisoa"* I managed to resolve the issue. Below is the code I used so if anyone has the same issue, here's the answer:

```
private void CreateTreeStructure(XDocument xDoc)
{
    foreach (var element in xDoc.Root.Elements("Category"))
    {
        var node = new TreeNode(element.Attribute("Name").Value);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
        if (element.HasElements) 
            ReadChildren(element.Element("Categories"), node);
    }
}

private void ReadChildren(XElement element, TreeNode node)
{
    foreach (var child in element.Elements("Category"))
    {
        var childNode = new TreeNode(child.Attribute("Name").Value);
        node.Nodes.Add(childNode);
        if(child.HasElements)
            ReadChildren(child.Element("Categories"), childNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Elements` instead of `Descendants`?  It sounds like it only returns direct children.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx

Comment: Where should I use Elements instead of Descendants then? Everywhere or in the foreach-part or ...?

Comment: Found it! :) Put your comment in an answer and I'll mark it as the right answer! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `Elements` method instead of `Descendants` it will only return direct children.  This should resolve the issue.

The `Elements` documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx).